# Запись информации в txt-файл

Tags: python, функции, filewriter

Не могу понять, почему мой data.txt остаётся пустым при таком коде

```
def summ(one, two):
    f = open('data.txt', 'w')
    result = one + two
    print(result)
    f.write(str(result))
    f.close()


summ(2, 7)
```

Comment: Может, `data.txt` не тот проверяешь либо текстовый редактор кеширует. В самом коде-то ошибок нет.

Comment: @hoefling я только что заметила, что у меня не работает конкретно в vs code, а в IDLE работает. Может мне нужно что-то установить?

Comment: Твой код будет создавать `data.txt` в рабочей директории (т.е. там, откуда запускаешь скрипт), она может быть разная в зависимости от среды. Добавь строку а-ля `print(os.getcwd())` в функцию `summ`, посмотри вывод после запуска и проверь наличие файла в той директории, которую скрипт напечатает. Можешь изменить код, чтобы он писал `data.txt` в ту же директорию, где скрипт лежит, а-ля `f = open(os.path.join(__file__, '..', 'data.txt'), 'w')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш `data.txt` не остается пустым, вы просто смотрите не на тот `data.txt`. При таком коде у вас создается этот файл там, откуда вы запустили ваш код (прим., если вы находились в папке А, а скрипт в папке B, то `python ~/B/my_script.py` все равно создаст файл в папке А.